# Shortcut to dictate text in Turkish assumes English when run by Siri

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I have the following shortcut set up. Previously I could run this with Siri, it would open a dictation dialogue and transcribe Turkish text. It behaved the same way when I run it via the Shortcuts app.

[image: iOS Shortcut to transcribe Turkish text]

Now I find that when I launch it via Siri, it only transcribes English, trying to make sense of my (admittedly limited) Turkish words as English ones. Yet, when I run it via the Shortcuts app it performs correctly.

It could be a separate question, but that "This action won't be supported in future versions of Shortcuts" is a bit worrying.. they don't give any idea of what to replace it. Had to add that because otherwise, Siri would try to get the text without the transcription dialog and it would fail.