# Invoking shortcut via Siri overrides dictation language specification

Tags: internationalization, shortcuts-app

When I activate a shortcut using Siri, the language specification in the Dictation action appears to be ignored, causing the Dictation to use the phone's default language rather than the one specified. (The language specification works correctly when the shortcut is invoked manually from the Shortcuts app.) How can I prevent this?

My example is happening on a Spanish phone trying to accept dictation in English, but I see that it's happening on [an English phone requesting dictation in Turkish](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462637/shortcut-to-dictate-text-in-turkish-assumes-english-when-run-by-siri) as well.